# Constraint violation merge Entity when adding map<String, Entity>

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, dictionary

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    String user_Name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="userfriendmap")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="userName")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    Map<String, Friend> friends;
}



@Entity
public class Friend implements Serializable{

    @Id 
    String userName;
}
```

I use Hibernate
I have these entities. One user has a map of friends. 
 First user1 add friend2 to the map, then user2 add friend1 to the map, 
then user1 add friend3 to the map, but when user3 add friend1 when I make mergeUser I have an error of Constraint violation.

The problem is that it creates a table userfriendmap with 3 attributes but only two are part of the primary key, and it needs to be the three of them.

The table userfriendmap have 
userName PK, friends_userName FK, User_user_Name PK FK

I don't know how to solve this. I don't know if it is correct how I make the table for the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of mapping this is as below. Note that I am using a surrogate key and use the @MapKey attribute which keys the map based on attribute of the associated value rather than a database column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "user_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "friendships", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id"))
    @MapKey(name = "userName")
    private Map<String, User> friends;

    public User(){
        friends = new HashMap<String, User>();
    }

    //force clients through add/remove to maintain two-way friendship
    public Map<String, User> getFriends() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(friends);
    }

    //assumes become mutual friends
    public void addFriend(User friend) {
        friends.put(friend.userName, friend);
        friend.friends.put(this.userName, this);
    }

    //assumes remove mutual friendship
    public void removeFriend(User friend) {
        friends.remove(friend.userName);
        friend.friends.remove(this.userName);
    }

    public User getFriend(String userName) {
        return friends.get(userName);
    }

    public void setUsername(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
@Test
public void testSaveUser(){

    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setUsername("user_1");

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setUsername("user_2");

    User user3 = new User();
    user3.setUsername("user_3");

    user1.addFriend(user2);
    user2.addFriend(user3);

    dao.saveUser(user1);
}
```

Join Table Data:

```
1   2
2   1
2   3
3   2
```

Comment: That was the solution for my problem! Thank you so much!